# React Router cannot detect match props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using react-router-dom v4, and had a hard time implementing routers in a way that params is passed.

```
const routing = (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/app" component={Mainpage} />
      <Route exact path="/app/documents" component={Documents} />
      <Route exact path="/app/quizzes" component={Quizzes} />
      <Route exact path="/app/new" component={Documents} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

const Quizzes = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/app/quizzes" component={QuizzesInterface} />
      <Route exact path="/app/quizzes/:id" component={QuizInterface} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
)

const QuizzesInterface = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <Background />
    <Interface status='quizzes' index={0}/>
  </div>
)

const QuizInterface = ({match}) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <Background />
      <Interface status='quizzes' index={match.params.id}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When I test localhost:3000/app/quizzes, the QuizzesInterface loads fine, but when I test localhost:3000/app/quizzes/1, say, the QuizInterface is not reached. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting both to have `strict` as well

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove return from QuizInterface

```
const QuizInterface = ({match}) => (
    <div>
      <Background />
      <Interface status='quizzes' index={match.params.id}/>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: That's not it. I just tried making both QuizInterface and QuizzesInterface into functions but still only the first endpoint works...

Comment: What do you mean functions? They already are. In any case you still were missing that return.

Comment: @MichaelSun I notice you only have `return` on the `QuizInterface`.

Comment: Does it load any component at all? or is it a blank page?

Comment: It's a blank page... - the <Background /> isn't loading either

Comment: Updated answer. Missed the issue earlier. Its a dumb/functional component. You dont need to return. Same as  QuizzesInterface

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that everywhere in your App you have used the exact keyword which works alright when you don't have nested Routes but as soon as you have nested Routes it will cause problems.

In you case you have Quizzes Routes Configured as

```
<Route exact path="/app/quizzes" component={Quizzes} />
```

Now Quizzes component has two Routes

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/app/quizzes" component={QuizzesInterface} />
  <Route exact path="/app/quizzes/:id" component={QuizInterface} />
</Switch>
```

So when your url path is `/app/quizzes/1`, it doesn't match `exact path="/app/quizzes"` and hence `Quizzes` component isn't rendered which makes it obvious that any nested Routes that it contains won't render

the solution is to not use `exact` for Route paths that have nested Routes, but use `Switch` and order your Routes correctly

```
const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="/app/documents" component={Documents} />
      <Route path="/app/quizzes" component={Quizzes} />
      <Route path="/app/new" component={Documents} />
      <Route path="/app" component={Mainpage} />
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

const Quizzes = ({match}) => (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/app/quizzes/:id" component={QuizInterface} />
      <Route path="/app/quizzes" component={QuizzesInterface} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
)
```

> **P.S.** You can use `exact` keyword for Routes but ensure that they don't
>   contain nested Routes